# Minikube volumes

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Minikube is supposed to make it simple to run Kubernetes locally,  not only for "getting started" but also for "day-to-day development workflows".

source : https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/ROADMAP.md#goals

But I can also read that : "PersistentVolumes are mapped to a directory inside the minikube VM. The Minikube VM boots into a tmpfs, so most directories will not be persisted across reboots (minikube stop)"

source : https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/#persistent-volumes

So what if my developments need persistent storage (MySQL database, mongodb database, ...) ? Do I need to throw my Minikube and install directly the full Kubernetes ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the answer from a Minikube contributer, confirming there was a problem in the documentation :

> I've reworded the readme to make a little more sense.
>
> The host is the computer you're running minikube on. This is only
>   exposed to the VM through the mounted host folders
>   https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/host_folder_mount.md
>
> The guest, or minikube VM, will persist certain folders to a disk
>   stored on the host (something like
>   ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/disk.vmdk). Files stored in certain
>   directories in the minikube VM will persist between start/stops, but
>   not deletes.

source : https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1184

Answer (score 20):

This is covered in [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/#persistent-volumes). The relevant section starts right after the sentence that you've already quoted:

> However, Minikube is configured to persist files stored under the following host directories:
>
> - /data
> - /var/lib/localkube
> - /var/lib/docker
>
> Here is an example PersistentVolume config to persist data in the ‘/data’ directory:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: PersistentVolume
> metadata:
>   name: pv0001
> spec:
>   accessModes:
>     - ReadWriteOnce
>   capacity:
>     storage: 5Gi
>   hostPath:
>     path: /data/pv0001/
> ```

Simply declare `hostPath` volumes that are mapped to any directory in `/data` on the host, and these should persist across reboots.

Comment: "should" ? so you don't know more than me right ? Cause what I understand is you can create volumes but the "host" will be minikube VM, that's what is written in the documentation you've just quoted.

Comment: To be clear, you say : "Simply declare hostPath volumes", when doc says : "Minikube supports PersistentVolumes of type hostPath. These PersistentVolumes are mapped to a directory inside the minikube VM."

Comment: "These PersistentVolumes are mapped to a directory inside the minikube VM." -- Yes. And the doc says that this directory is persisted across reboots of the Minikube VM. That what you've asked for in your question, wasn't it?

Comment: Are we reading the same doc ? Mine says : "most directories will NOT be persisted across reboots"

Comment: Yes. But `/data/` will.

Comment: After a discussion with some minikube guy, he has made a pull request to correct the misleading documentation (You are right about /data/ though).

Comment: as of 2022SEP document url should be changed to https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/

Answer (score -4):

Or you can try https://github.com/reachlin/k8s0/, which is a full-fledged kubernetes installed on a single host using ansible.